# updating the column of SQL in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to update my one column name 'Con_Id' of a table name 'Request' correspond to One column name 'Req_Id'(Primary key). initially my Con_Id column is null

my code is

```
public void appc(string idk, string status)
{
    var res= (from f in td.Requests
                where f.Req_Id==status
                select f).First();
    res.Con_Id=idk;
    td.SaveChanges();
}
```

but i got the error that "Sequence contain no elements".can anyone help to solve this error.

Comment: This means that res returned nothing it means "from f in td.Requests
         where f.Req_Id==status" record like that doesn't exist

Comment: no but in controller and in wrapper class status hold the req_id value

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside appc method copy a value of status parameter and check in db if You have that record or not(it's string so it might be a problem of case sensitivness).

Comment: in db record is present

Comment: It's impossible - "Sequence contain no elements" is an Exception thrown by ".First()" extension method which means there is no such record.

Comment: I can send u screenshot if u dont belive

Comment: Send me two screenshots. One with breakpoint inside appc method with watch on status variable and second one on database with the record. Upload them somewhere and send a link

Comment: i m new here and i have only 3 reputation so i can not add image untill i earned atleast 10 reputation

Comment: upload it and provide links in comment